# Varnish frontend server, Litespeed backend server

Tags: varnish, litespeed

I wonder if someone could advise what I'm doing wrong.

I have Varnish set up on a frontend server, and this is working. I can put the IP address for several public websites into this (including CNN) into the configuration, and they are cached by Varnish.

When I put one of my site IP address' into Varnish, I get a 404 error back from the Litespeed server - this shows it's connecting to the server, but obviously not picking up the correct site to show Varnish. I have several domains on the Litespeed server, each with it's own IP address. The same happens with the direct URL.

This is I guess a problem with the Litespeed configuration - but any assistance would be appreciated.

For reference, I'm using the VCL configuration file for PageCache, which is a Magento module for Varnish.

Justin

```
# default backend definition.  Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
  .host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
  .port = "80";
}

# admin backend with longer timeout.
backend admin {
  .host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
  .port = "80";
  .first_byte_timeout = 18000s;
  .between_bytes_timeout = 18000s;
}

# add your Magento server IP to allow purges from the backend
acl purge {
  "localhost";
  "127.0.0.1";
}


sub vcl_recv {
if (req.restarts == 0) {
    if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
        req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
    } else {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
    }
}

if (req.request != "GET" &&
  req.request != "HEAD" &&
  req.request != "PUT" &&
  req.request != "POST" &&
  req.request != "TRACE" &&
  req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
  req.request != "DELETE" &&
  req.request != "PURGE") {
    /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
    return (pipe);
}

# purge request
if (req.request == "PURGE") {
    if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
        error 405 "Not allowed.";
    }
    ban("obj.http.X-Purge-Host ~ " + req.http.X-Purge-Host + " && obj.http.X-Purge-URL ~ " + req.http.X-Purge-Regex + " && obj.http.Content-Type ~ " + req.http.X-Purge-Content-Type);
    error 200 "Purged.";
}

# switch to admin backend configuration
if (req.http.cookie ~ "adminhtml=") {
    set req.backend = admin;
}

# we only deal with GET and HEAD by default    
if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
    return (pass);
}

# normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://[^/]+", "");

# static files are always cacheable. remove SSL flag and cookie
if (req.url ~ "^/(media|js|skin)/.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|css|js|swf|ico)$") {
    unset req.http.Https;
    unset req.http.Cookie;
}

# not cacheable by default
if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Https) {
    return (pass);
}

# do not cache any page from
# - index files
# - ...
if (req.url ~ "^/(index)") {
    return (pass);
}

# as soon as we have a NO_CACHE cookie pass request
if (req.http.cookie ~ "NO_CACHE=") {
    return (pass);
}

# normalize Aceept-Encoding header
# http://varnish.projects.linpro.no/wiki/FAQ/Compression
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
    if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
        # No point in compressing these
        remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
    } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
    } else {
        # unkown algorithm
        remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    }
}

# remove Google gclid parameters
set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+$",""); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA"
set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+&","?"); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA&foo=bar"
set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"&gclid=[^&]+",""); # strips when QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA" or QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA&bar=baz"

return (lookup);
}


sub vcl_hash {
hash_data(req.url);
if (req.http.host) {
    hash_data(req.http.host);
} else {
    hash_data(server.ip);
}
if (!(req.url ~ "^/(media|js|skin)/.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|css|js|swf|ico)$")) {
    call design_exception;
}
return (hash);
}

sub vcl_fetch {
if (beresp.status == 500) {
   set beresp.saintmode = 10s;
   return (restart);
}
set beresp.grace = 5m;

# add ban-lurker tags to object
set beresp.http.X-Purge-URL = req.url;
set beresp.http.X-Purge-Host = req.http.host;

if (beresp.status == 200 || beresp.status == 301 || beresp.status == 404) {
    if (beresp.http.Content-Type ~ "text/html" || beresp.http.Content-Type ~ "text/xml")     {
        if ((beresp.http.Set-Cookie ~ "NO_CACHE=") || (beresp.ttl < 1s)) {
            set beresp.ttl = 0s;
            return (hit_for_pass);
        }

        # marker for vcl_deliver to reset Age:
        set beresp.http.magicmarker = "1";

        # Don't cache cookies
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    } else {
        # set default TTL value for static content
        set beresp.ttl = 4h;
    }
    return (deliver);
}

return (hit_for_pass);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
# debug info
if (resp.http.X-Cache-Debug) {
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
        set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;
    } else {
       set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    }
    set resp.http.X-Cache-Expires = resp.http.Expires;
} else {
    # remove Varnish/proxy header
    remove resp.http.X-Varnish;
    remove resp.http.Via;
    remove resp.http.Age;
    remove resp.http.X-Purge-URL;
    remove resp.http.X-Purge-Host;
}

if (resp.http.magicmarker) {
    # Remove the magic marker
    unset resp.http.magicmarker;

    set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
    set resp.http.Expires = "Mon, 31 Mar 2008 10:00:00 GMT";
    set resp.http.Age = "0";
}
}

sub design_exception {
}
```

And...

```
START=yes
NFILES=131072
MEMLOCK=82000
INSTANCE=$(uname -n)

## Alternative 2, Configuration with VCL
#
# Listen on port 6080, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to
# one content server selected by the vcl file, based on the request.  Use a 1GB
# fixed-size cache file.

DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
         -T localhost:6082 \
         -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
         -S /etc/varnish/secret \
         -s malloc,256m"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I needed! [Configure multiple sites with Varnish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334023/configure-multiple-sites-with-varnish)

I needed to put the virtual host names into the configuration file. Followed this guide and had it work in moments!

Answer (score 0):

To what port is your Varnish server bound? And what port do you use for Litespeed?

It would be useful if you could post your config files here to give you further advices.

Comment: Varnish and Litespeed are both bound to port 80 currently. As they're on separate servers, I'd hope that wouldn't matter. I've added code to my original post. Thanks.

Comment: I've also tried putting Varnish on a different port, by the way. No difference which makes me think Litespeed has the issue.

Comment: Using port 80 on different servers is OK. Have you checked the incoming requests in your Litespeed when you try to access it via varnish? Maybe some varnish rule modifies your request in such a way that Litespeed can't deliver it correctly? You might compare the log entry that is created when you call Litespeed directly with the log entry that is created when you call varnish.

Comment: Thanks Marc - sorted as per the above. Cheers for your assistance, as I was following it before stumbling upon this.